# rewrite rule htaccess php multiple vars

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, var

i need a simple rewrite rule with mulitple vars from

from:
 **index.php?id=steckbrief&art=steinkauz**

to 
**/steckbrief/steinkauz/**
  or

**/steckbrief/steinkauz.html**

i found several examples, but perhaps another line of my rewrite rules blocks the rewrite?
because i also want the single var and get it with:
**RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]**

something like this :

`RewriteRule ^steckbrief/?$ /index.php?id=steckbrief=$1&art=$2 [L,NC,QSA]`

...

`RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)\$ index.php?id=$1&art=$2 [NC]`
works so far:
`RewriteRule ^steckbrief/([0-9A-Za-z-]+)$ index.php?id=steckbrief&art=$1`

i am new to it 
 
thanks for advice

example map:
http://steinkauz.info/steckbrief/steinkauz.html

Comment: A catch-all `(.*)` will confllct with subsequent rules, because it potentially captures *all* path segments. See also [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode` to do that.
This is the easiest way.

Regex: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)$ index.php?id=$0 [NC]`

PHP: `$art = explode("/", $_GET["id"])[1];`

Comment: `id=$1` only appends the first capture group. Either use `$0` to split it, or add `&art=$2` for the second path segment.

Comment: @mario my mistake, i was copied and pasted from the question